# Access report: Determining the form the report was called from

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

Is there anyway to determine the form name that the report was called from? I would like to write some VBA code in report to determine where is the report was called from.
I have Access 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a report like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportFoo", acPreview, , , , Me.Name
```

and something like this in the report:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If "" <> Me.OpenArgs Then
        MsgBox Me.OpenArgs ' display caller form's name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested it on Ms Access 2003 before I post it.

Comment: The OpenArgs parameter did not exist in Access before 2002, I think (not sure if it was in 2002, either -- it might have been introduced in 2003).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you set it up yourself. You could write to a variable or, if the form remains open, store the information on the form.

Comment: Umm, if he doesn't know what form is opening the report how can he store the form name in the report?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get your point, I said store the information on the form if the form remain open, the forms can be checked from the report, or the form and report name are written to a variable, yesno?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a report_caller class that always opens any reports.  It needs a method called "openReport" that takes in the name of the form doing the calling and the name of the report being opened.  Then it can have a public method to allow the report to get the name of the form that was opened.